# How to create a custom stream like stdin in python

Tags: python

I was wondering if there is a `"stream"`(I don't know if that is what you guys call it) like `stdin/stdout/stderr` that can be referenced later using `open()`. I was doing this for temporary data that is rather large and wanted to put it to a stream instead of a variable.

Would I use `subprocess`?

Comment: `steam` does not necessarily mean that you have to use `subprocess`. Please be more specific.

Comment: The idea of stdin and the other IO streams are that for each application they get a dedicated stream to save data into. I want to know if I can create a custom one that I can use to put special info in.

Comment: What are you planning to do with it? If you're going to pass it to [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), then `open` takes a filename (as in, the name of a file on the system). So the abstraction you're looking for, in that case, is called a *file*. The built-in [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) module can help with making short-lived files. If you're planning to do something else with it, perhaps you could clarify your use case and we can provide something that works for your situation.

Comment: You probably looking for a pipe https://docs.python.org/3/library/pipes.html

Comment: `tempfile` seems like a good solution. I know that files were used for storing data although I thought that pipes might've been more efficient for something like this although I could be wrong

Comment: so with `pipes` it shows that when using `read()` that it returns all the text in uppercase is there any reason for that?

Comment: That's only in the example because of the line ```t.append('tr a-z A-Z', '--')```. If you skip that it's read like it's written

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways:

`tempfile` is a module that can create temporary files for you with or without name and store them on disk and in memory which is similar to the next solution:

`pipes` is a module the allows you to create pipes which can be read and written to. These are both viable solutions